# prove/disprove $\Delta$ is strongly connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, simplicial-complex

Let $\Delta$ be a simplicial complex and $F_1,...,F_n$ be the facets of $\Delta$. Let $\Delta_1$ be another simplicial complex and $F_1,...,F_{n-1}$ be the facets of $\Delta_1$. Assume $\Delta$ and $\Delta_1$ are pure simplicial complexes and $\Delta_1$ is strongly connected. Prove/disprove $\Delta$ is strongly connected.

Comment: Maybe you want to add the definition of a strongly connected simplicial complex.

Comment: Please see definition of strongly connected:http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-02/S0002-9939-99-04947-3/S0002-9939-99-04947-3.pdf    and  http://rms.unibuc.ro/bulletin/pdf/53-2/Yasemi.pdf

Comment: I have no idea why you think this could happen. If $\Delta_1$ is a triangle, then this is (vacuously) strongly connected, while if you "glue" this by another triangle (so they look like a butterfly) and call this $\Delta$, then this new complex is pure and not strongly connected.